# Trouble using PHP-ExcelReader - bad xls file?

Tags: php, excel

I'm trying to import data from an excel file using [PHP-ExcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) and having trouble. The file is generated by a program at work. (although this is an unofficial project, I'm just an enthusiast)

When I read the file the data is weird. Cells in one column that are normally 4 characters are truncated to 2. Most other columns seem to have no consistency in when cells are truncated, except that the entire text is never there. If I edit just one cell using Libreoffice, save and import the same file, everything displays fine. Code is something like this:

```
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
    $data->read($filename);
    echo "<table>\n";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++) {
            echo "<td>";
            if (isset($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j])) {
                echo $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j];
            }
            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
```

The idea is this file would be generated by multiple users at least once a day, so it's unrealistic to have them save the file, edit it and re-save before uploading. Do you have any suggestions on how I can import this file as is?

Answer (score 0):

I have same trouble with you. My xls files are downloaded from SSRS. 
If I read directly after downloading, string and number data will be retrieved as weird data.
For example :

data in excel 1,040,809,656.00
but Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader retrieves [$-1,040,809,6561,040,809,6561,040,809,6561,040,809,6561,040,809,6561,040,809,6561,040,809,656]1,040,809,6561,040,809,6561,040,809,6561,040,809,656.1,040,809,6561,040,809,656

My temporary solution is just open the file and save-as it (without editing).